# Not getting expected result for mouse hover test script in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, action

Below is the code snippet for mouse hover on an element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.setProperty("Webdriver.ie.driver","D://IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.amity.edu/");

    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement MainTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='main']/ul[2]/li[2]/a"));
    action.moveToElement(MainTab).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: Can u share the url or html code and what is the error you are getting while trying to hover.

Comment: Some words of explanation usually are appreciated on stack overflow.

Comment: please add some HTML code and explain what you are getting

Comment: It is working in chrome, which version you use for IE

Comment: I am getting message "You are using unsupported command line flag -- ignore certificate errors. Stability and security will suffer" after chrome browser launch. and also the URL is not getting launched. getting below exception:

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code, It will work in `chrome` and `firefox` browsers.

Due to some issues with `IE` browser, Action class is not working with `IE Browser`.

Refer this [url](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4633), for more details.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");   //path for your browser.
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.amity.edu/");

String page_title = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(page_title);

WebElement main_menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='megamenu main-nav']/li/a[text()='Campuses']"));  // Get main menu
WebElement child_menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='megamenu main-nav']//li/a[text()='Chennai']")); // get Submenu called Chennai 

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(main_menu).perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(child_menu));     //wait for element
act.moveToElement(child_menu).click().perform();
```

Comment: Hello Jainish, thanks for your reply. 
I am getting message "You are using unsupported command line flag -- ignore certificate errors. Stability and security will suffer" after chrome browser launch. And also the URL (http://www.amity.edu/) is not getting launched. I don't know what exactly the issue is as for my application I am able to successfully launch the chrome browser. Can you help on this.

Comment: Please Update the chrome driver. and provide proper path for launch the chrome browser.

Comment: Please do update me, If you have face other query related to this question. And Have your problem is resolved?

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's work for you.